# QWinEventNotifier: event notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread (movetothread and qserialport)

Tags: c++, qt

# I'm sorry about the way describe the message because I am French-speaking, and I am a beginner in this forum.je hope that now the comment is clearer

```
void Serie::Cfg()
{
   serial =  new QSerialPort();
   _thrSerial = new QThread;
   this->moveToThread(_thrSerial);
   serial->moveToThread(_thrSerial);
   _thrSerial->start();

   connect(_thrSerial, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(PortProcess()));
   connect(_thrSerial, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));

   connect(_thrSerial, SIGNAL(finished()), _thrSerial, SLOT(terminate()));
   connect(_thrSerial, SIGNAL(finished()), _thrSerial, SLOT(quit()));
}
void Serie::PortProcess()
{ 
   connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(Receive8bits()));//,Qt::QueuedConnection);
   connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this, SLOT(ErrorHandle(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));
   connect(_thrSerial, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
}
void Serie::Receive8bits()
{
   QByteArray lTmpByteArray = this->serial->readAll();
   if(!lTmpByteArray.isEmpty())
   {
       for(int i= 0; i< lTmpByteArray.size(); i +=1)
       {
          lData = lTmpByteArray[i]& 0x000000FF;
          FrameStateAdd(lData);
       }

   }
}

Serie::~Serie()
{
  if(serial !=NULL)
  {
    if(serial->isOpen())
        serial->close();//it is the source of problem
    delete serial;// problem
    serial = NULL;
  }
}
```

When i decide to close the port of qserialport(serial), i have this error :

```
`Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
 ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. 
 Current thread 122f1b28. Receiver '' (of type 'QSerialPort') was created in thread 146b8c40", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 502.`
```

Comment: It seems the instances of `Serie` and `QSerialPort` are running in different threads, even though you call `moveToThread` on both. The docs say `moveToThread` fails when the object has a parent, does your `Serie` instance have a parent?

Comment: moveToThread works well in the normal case, except to close the port of qserialport gives the previous beug.      
 I use a class Serie where i declare my thread.
then Serie is declared as a variable in another class called chargeur used in the main window. 
      void chargeur::initChargeur(QString com)
      {
        _serie = new Serie ( _Com , QSerialPort::Baud115200,getInterFrame());
      }

      void MainWindow::InstanceChargeur(QString acom,int avitesse)
      {
             _chargeur = new chargeur(CHARGEUR_ID);
       }

Comment: As the problem occurs in the destructor, it seems you call delete from another thread

Comment: Maybe `deleteLater` solves this